# ViewFlipper automatic slideshow without button

Tags: java, android, jquery

Could anyone please help me with the below java code as I want to create a image slideshow without a click of a button. I want the view flipper to automatically switch through the different iamges without a click of a button. I want it to keep on showing all the images again and again, without a click of a button. I have deleted the button in my XML file as I dont require it.

Java File Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        int mFlipping = 0 ; // Initially flipping is off
        Button mButton ; // Reference to button available in the layout to start and stop the flipper

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            /** Click event handler for button */
            OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper1);

                    if(mFlipping==0){
                        /** Start Flipping */
                        flipper.startFlipping();
                        mFlipping=1;
                        mButton.setText(R.string.str_btn_stop);
                    }
                    else{
                        /** Stop Flipping */
                        flipper.stopFlipping();                 
                        mFlipping=0;
                        mButton.setText(R.string.str_btn_start);
                    }
                }
            };

            /** Getting a reference to the button available in the resource */
            mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

            /** Setting click event listner for the button */
            mButton.setOnClickListener(listener);


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

XML File

```
<ViewFlipper 
            android:id="@+id/flipper1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:flipInterval="3000"
            android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
            android:outAnimation="@android:anim/slide_out_right"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"

            >


            <ImageView 
                android:src="@drawable/img1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/str_img1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

            <ImageView 
                android:src="@drawable/img2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/str_img2"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

            <ImageView 
                android:src="@drawable/img3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/str_img3"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

            <ImageView 
                android:src="@drawable/img4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/str_img4"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

            <ImageView 
                android:src="@drawable/img5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/str_img5"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

        </ViewFlipper>      


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For(int mflipping:0;mflipping less than total images-1 length; mflipping++)
Curly brases starts
Flipper.startflipping();
//Delay for sometime
Curly Brases End
Flipper.stopflipping();

Sodu code,write your code now

Comment: could you please rewrite the code for me as i am a bit stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove button listener and try.

```html
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        int mFlipping = 0 ; // Initially flipping is off
      

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper1);
  
                    if(mFlipping==0){
                        /** Start Flipping */
                        flipper.startFlipping();
                        mFlipping=1;

                    }
                    else{
                        /** Stop Flipping */
                        flipper.stopFlipping();                 
                        mFlipping=0;
                      
                    }
                }
            };       

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
    }
```